# Convert type in set & get c#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, getter-setter

I am wondering about the conversion of types in the class definition section. For example is it possible to convert from long to decimal in the get/set section?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide your code and explain what is not working. See best practice for asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Just *cast*.

```
get => (decimal)someLong;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to make a type conversion anywhere in c# code. If property get/set could only do a single value return/assign then they wouldn't be needed/you wouldn't get the opportunity to code them up at all; the c# team would have made it so the compiler did it for you as a shortcut

Here's an example:

```
private long _backingField = 0;
public decimal PropertyName{
  get{
    return Convert.ToDecimal(_backingField);
  }
}
```

Mildly curious as to why you'd bother though; by making a property you're saying "the developer that uses this property must supply/expect a decimal" - why then store it in a long (or vice versa) - why not just keep it as a decimal they supplied, and give it back as a decimal when asked?

If you need it as a long for some internal process, covert it as part of the prices, not as part of the storage..

Comment: Because the data types comes from an EDM and its type is specified in another DB, in our DB we should change it

Comment: Still didn't really get why the conversion must happen inside the property but as noted it works just fine